# How to convert Dec 2 1991 12:00AM to 12/02/1991

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var str = "Dec 02 1991 12:00"; 
var new_Date = str.substring(0,str.length - 6);
var DateOfBirth = $filter('date')(new Date(new_Date), 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: use moment.js for the easy life

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this.

You can parse the date using the 'Date' constructor: `new Date("Dec 02 1991 12:00")`.

Then you have a Date object in which you have methods to get the month, the day and the year (see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)).

Here is an example for what you are trying to achieve:

```
var str = "Dec 02 1991 12:00"; 
var date = new Date(str);

var month = date.getUTCMonth();
var day = date.getUTCDay();
var year = date.getUTCFullYear();

var dateOfBirth = ((month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month) + "/" + ((day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day) + "/" + year;
```